# get_the_categories() but exclude children of "Uncategorized"

Tags: categories

In this function, I need to exclude any categories from $categories which are children of "Uncategorized".

```
function get_cats(){
    $post_cats= array();
    $categories = get_the_category();
    foreach($categories as $cat){  
        array_push($post_cats, $cat->cat_ID);
    }
    return $post_cats;
}
```

Thanks in advance if you can help.

Answer (score 1):

Check if `$cat->category_parent != 1` (assuming `uncategorized` has the default ID of 1). If your subcategories are deeper than one level you'll need to use [`get_ancestors`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_ancestors) to determine the top level category.

Answer (score 1):

It should be like this,

```
function get_cats(){
$post_cats= array();
$categories = get_the_category();
  foreach($categories as $cat){
     if($cat->category_parent == 1 || $cat->cat_ID == 1)
     continue;
     array_push($post_cats, $cat->cat_ID);
  }
return $post_cats; }
```

Now the Un-categorized category and with this children filtered. You can remove this category from the admin if you need.

Check [this blog](http://computeraxe.com/how-to-get-rid-of-that-uncategorized-category-in-wordpress-blogs/)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this can help (inside `foreach`):

```
if( $cat->cat_name != 'Uncategorized' ) {
    array_push( $post_cats, $cat->cat_ID );
}
```

**Update**:

You may want to use [`post_is_in_descendant_category`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/in_category#Testing_if_a_post_is_in_a_descendant_category) function:

```
if( $cat->cat_name != 'Uncategorized'
    && !post_is_in_descendant_category(
           get_term_by( 'name', 'Uncategorized', 'category' ),
           $post
        )
) {
    array_push( $post_cats, $cat->cat_ID );
}
```

(not tested, sorry)

Nothe, that [`post_is_in_descendant_category`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/in_category#Testing_if_a_post_is_in_a_descendant_category) should be defined in your `functions.php`, please check the link.

Comment: Thanks brownian, will this exclude the child cats of uncategorized too? Or do they have to be explicitly included by name as well?

Comment: @N2Mystic i've updated the answer